# Viewing contents of table variable when debugging in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2012, table-variable, watch-window

In the watch window whilst debugging in Sql Server 2012, we get to see the values of regular variables, we can look at xml in a special window and same with sql strings, but for a table variable it just says (table).

I'd really like to know if there is any way to peek inside that table variable at that moment and check on the contents.

**EDIT:**

I have discovered that Visual Studio (for a long time now), has had a "Table" visualizer alongside Xml, Html, and Text. This does not help me here, but it underscores the point I made originally that it is a very doable feature. I'm very disappointed in general with the Sql Server SSMS team vs the Visual Studio team. I think Visual Studio developers in Redmond ought to be forced every 5 years to do a "tour of duty" for 2 or 3 sprints on the SSMS team. They could help it sooo much if they did that.

Thank you.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900857/how-to-see-the-values-of-a-table-variable-at-debug-time-in-t-sql for workarouds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I'm sorry to report that this is still not possible in SQL Server 2012. The feature has been requested, received a lot of upvotes, but was discarded after ***four years*** of deliberation:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/363054

Comment: I am still keeping my fingers crossed, if in case microsoft launches this feature sometime in near future.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still interested in a work around, but I'll mark that as an answer. good grief...All they need is another Debug Window Visualizer to work along-side Text, Xml amd Html. I could prob write it myself!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: `select * from @temp_table`

Comment: I will definitely try that if you can tell me where I would type that. I don't recall an immediate window while debugging. thanks.