# How to view data in table variables during debugging session in MS SQL Management Studio 2012?

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2012, ssms, table-variable

I would like to debug a complex T-SQL script using SSMS 2012.

I can run the script in debug mode and place breakpoints, as well as step through my script, but I can't see the values stored in my table variables.

In the `Locals` window I see all these variables, but their value is shown as `(table)`:

[image: Locals window]

There is no way to view the content of the variable through the context menu or by clicking on the variable.

I tried to use the `Immediate Window` to run a query on the table variable, but this seems not to work either.

[image: Immediate Window]

Any idea how I can get the values from my table variables in the debug session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the values of a table variable at debug time in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900857/how-to-see-the-values-of-a-table-variable-at-debug-time-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whilst I can't find any documetation, anywhere, that explicitly states that you cannot inspect table variables, I don't believe that it's possible. From [Transact-SQL Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645997.aspx)

> **Locals** and **Watch**. These windows display currently allocated Transact-SQL expressions. *Expressions are Transact-SQL clauses that evaluate to a single, scalar expression*. The Transact-SQL debugger supports viewing expressions that reference Transact-SQL variables, parameters, or the built-in functions that have names that start with @@. These windows also display the data values that are currently assigned to the expressions.

(*My emphasis*)

That is, you can only inspect scalars.

As to your attempt to use the Immediate window, the [Limitations on Debugger Command and Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms165035(v=vs.100).aspx) says:

> The **Immediate** window is displayed, but you cannot do anything useful with it, such as setting a variable to a value, or querying the database.

---

I've never really used the debugger much - everytime I've looked into it, I encounter limitations like this.

That's why I still tend to use "old-skool"/"printf" approaches to debug SQL - include extra `SELECT *`s liberally throughout the code showing the current state of tables, and extra `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` messages that show other states, etc. And then just run the code normally, until you've bashed it into shape.

Comment: Thank you for your research, mine did not yield any results too. I just didn't want to believe it is not possible, for it renders the debugger completely unusable in my eyes. The problem with "old-skool"-debugging is that we have just "combed" the code to contain no debug/commented out/unreachable statements (as required by our coding policy) and I need to bring them back again ...

Answer (score 12):

Using the next code you can see the content of your table as XML.

```
DECLARE @v XML = (SELECT * FROM <tablename> FOR XML AUTO)
```

It is useful to check what your SELECT statements return. I tested it and it works.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748570/1726308).

Comment: This is not working. I cannot able to see the @v in locals window.

Comment: @Naren I've verified this. It does work in local window and I can see the values populated in the @v variable. I'm using SQL Server management studio for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You can add ",ROOT('rootNodeName')" to the "FOR XML" clause. This will collect multiple rows (if any) under a single root, which makes for a legal XML document, which can be viewed with the XML visualizer instead of the text visualizer.

Answer (score 2):

I just simply put in select statements into my script and it displays it to the results window..

select * from @VarTable;

now as I step thru my code and hit the select it will display the values.
Then I either comment them out when done testing or set a Testing flag.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Including a select statement in the code is the only way I know and can think of.

Having a 'configuration' table in the database allows adding debugging code permanently to the SP, which helps if you have to debug it often. You can leave code like "if ({select logging level in config table}) = {debug} then select '@variable at location 1' as [@variable at location 1], * from @variable order by {some useful order}".

With the way I include the variable name and possibly the location (if there are several places where you need to check) in both the result and the column name, it makes it easy to tell apart the variables in the output even when a particular table variable has no rows, and you did not expect that.