# How to see temp table created by code in sql server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, temp-tables, global-temp-tables

I create a global temp table (i.e `##TheTable`) using C# code. I want to be able to see that temp table in SQL server management studio after the code runs completely.

Is it possible to do this ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: But after the code runs completely the temp table is gone.  That is why they call it temp.

Comment: paparazzo, not all temporary tables are removed after the code runs. Table variables are removed in this way, but temp tables are not automatically removed after the code runs.

Comment: @ZenoArrow right if you mean that it can still be there since the data flow is still open in some sort. If you debug in SSIS and you have not stopped the debug mode, then yes, the temporary table will still be there. But as soon as you stop the debug mode, the temporary table (also a ##tmpTable) will be gone.

Comment: @questionto42 Yes, when the temp tables are cleared (without explicitly deleting them) depends on when the session that created them is closed. For example, if you're working with a SQL Server database in SSMS, you could run SQL that creates a temp table that persists after the SQL has finished running, and it'll only be closed at the point when the user that created the temp tables had their database connection closed (e.g. by logging out of the SQL Server instance).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the code has finished and the session is closed, the temporary table will cease to exist. If you want to see it in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you need to keep the code session open until the data has been reviewed in SSMS.

Per [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection
>   after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are
>   referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.

As an alternative, there's a C# code option here that selects the data from the temporary table into a code variable for review in the code ... (and if the code is to exist, you could possibly write it to a file or review by another means) -- see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748570/3063884

Answer (score 34):

All temp tables are logged under SQL server > Databases > System Databases > tempdb -> Temporary Tables

Comment: SQL server > Databases > System Databases > tempdb -> Temporary Tables

Comment: I cannot see any temp table under the Temporary tables.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint after the creation of the temp table, and then checking in SSMS.  Don't forget to refresh the Temporary Tables folder as it does not update automatically.  ##tables should be persisted even after the connection/session has dropped.  #tables are only there for the session they are made in.

Comment: I tried it by NOT closing my connection and that did not work. I will try the breakpoint now.

Comment: Okay. The breakpoint works. But, why am I not able to see the temp table after the code (without breakpoints) has executed fully ? How to make it possible to still see the temp table without breakpoint ?

Comment: @InTheSkies To do that you need to not close the session to the server (via `connection.Close()` or disposing it), the server deletes all temporary tables a session creates when the session is closed.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Actually, I did not close the connection with conn.close(). That did not work.

Comment: @InTheSkies Without you showing your code we can't say, perhaps it is getting closed or disposed and you don't realize it. Or perhaps the connection gets garbage collected before you go check. Please edit your original question to show the code you want to test so we can make more informed answers.

Answer (score 6):

Create a test table

```
SELECT * INTO ##temp1
FROM dbo.SomeTable_Name
```

Now to check if table is there

```
SELECT  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O
WHERE O.xtype in ('U') 
AND O.ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##temp1')
```