# Getting data of temp table while debugging

Tags: sql-server

While debugging I am unable to watch temp table's value in sql server 2012.I am getting all of my variables value and even can print that but struggling with the temp tables .Is there any way to watch temp table's value?.

Comment: debugging what? your problem is definitely not with SQL Server,

Comment: I have made a stored procedure containing lots of variable ,temp tables and transaction .I have printed my variables as a check point ,When I execute my procedure I get the printed value in msg window but unable to watch what values my temp table is containing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, I've been trying to make this work also where I can view temp table data as I debug my stored procedure.  So far nothing works.

I've seen many links to methods on how to the do this, but ultimately they don't work the way a developer would want them to work.  For example: suppose one has several processes in the Stored Procedure that updates and modifies data in the same temp table, there is no way to see update on the fly for each process in the SP.

This is a VERY common request, yet no one seems to have a solution other than don't use Stored Procedures for complex processing due how difficult they are to debug.  If you're a .NET Core/EF 6 developer and have the correct PK,FK set for the database, one shouldn't really need to use Stored Procedures at all as it can all be handled by EF6 and debug code to view data results in your entities/models directly (usually in web API using models/entities).

Trying to retrieve the data from the tempdb is not possible even with the same connection (as has been suggested).

What is sometimes used is:
PRINT '#temptablename'
SELECT * FROM #temptablename

Dotted thruout the code, you can add a debug flag to the SP and selectively debug the output.  NOT ideal at all, but works for many situations.

But this MUST already be in the Stored Procedure before execution (not during).  And you must remember to remove the code prior to deployment to a production environment.

I'm surprised in 2022, we still have no solution to this other than don't use complex stored procedures or use .NET Core/EF 6 ... which in my humble opinion is the best approach for 2022 since SSMS and other tools like dbForge and RedGate can't accomplish this either.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides the concept of temporary table which helps the developer in a great way. These tables can be created at runtime and can do the all kinds of operations that one normal table can do. But, based on the table types, the scope is limited. These tables are created inside tempdb database.

While debugging, you can pause the SP at some point, write the select statement in your SP before the DROP table statement, the # table is available for querying.

select * from #temp

Answer (score 0):

I placed this code inside my stored procedure and I am able to see the temp table contents inside the "Locals" window.

```
INSERT INTO #temptable (columns) SELECT columns FROM sometable; -- populate your temp table
-- for debugging, comment in production
DECLARE @temptable XML = (SELECT * FROM #temptable FOR XML AUTO); -- now view @temptable in Locals window
```

This works on older SQL Server 2008 but newer versions would probably support a friendlier FOR JSON object.  Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748570/1129926