# Add watch to SQL select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, visual-studio-2017

I'm debugging this code in Visual Studio:

```
INSERT INTO @transactions
SELECT FirstDate
FROM #coo
```

During debug, before this query is executed, I want to see what the result of the select statement will be.

I added a watch for `SELECT FirstDate FROM #coo` but it says

> could not be evaluated

How can I see the result of the select statement before the result is inserted into `@transactions`?

Comment: Hi! did you try to see and run your `SELECT statement` on the application you were using??

Comment: No because a whole bunch of things are happening before this point in the stored proc.

Comment: Side note: You should always specify the columns list in an insert statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry I'm new to SQL, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: `insert into table (column1, column2)  values (value1, value2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748570/2063755) I was able to come up with a work around (until someone can answer the question).

I put

`DECLARE @beforeInsert XML = (SELECT * FROM @transactions FOR XML AUTO)`

before the insert statement, and then I put this after:

```
DECLARE @afterInsert XML = (SELECT * FROM @transactions FOR XML AUTO)
```

That way I could view the value of `@beforeInsert` and `@afterInsert` during debug and look at the difference to work out what was inserted.